# Best Way To Give Users Option To Select Dates "ALL TIME" in SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services, parameters, expression, ssrs-2012

I currently have a report that allows the users to select a @STARTDATE and @ENDDATE as parameters and I would like to also give them the option to select, if needed, the dates for ALL TIME.  I created an extra boolean parameter called "ALL TIME" which allows the users to select if they want all dates or not, by having them select Yes (True) or No (False).

The expression that I have for the default value of the parameter "ALL TIME" is currently
=iif(Parameters!ALL_TIME.Value,
What is the proper way to select all dates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please specify what code language you are using. Also, a snippet code will do a lot of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass all three parameters to your query. If "All Time" is selected, the values in the other two don't matter.

So you query might look something like..

```
SELECT * 
    FROM myTable
    WHERE (myDateColumn BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate OR @AllTime = 1)
```

That's it..